# How to resolve Django crispy-forms Template Syntax Error

Tags: python, html, django, django-crispy-forms

Hey I am trying to learn the Django crispy forms, so when I try putting/injecting the `{load crispy_forms_tags %}` I get the error below

**Error Message**

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /login/

'crispy_form_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
crispy_forms_field
crispy_forms_filters
crispy_forms_tags
crispy_forms_utils
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
```

**Code Below: HTML**

```
{% load crispy_form_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0   /css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"  crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% crispy form  %}


</body>
</html>
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class Accounts(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False, blank=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)
    verify_password = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserAccount(forms.Form):

class Meta:
    terms = (

        ('agree', 'Agree'),
        ('disagree', 'Disagree')
    )
    model = Accounts
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    verify_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    terms_and_conditions = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=terms) 
    fields = (

        'name',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'password',
        'verify_password',
        'terms_and_conditions'
    )


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper
    self.helper.form_method = 'POST'

    self.helper.layout = (

        'name', 
        'last_name',
        'phone', 
        'email', 
        'password',
        'verify_password',
        'terms_and_conditions',
        Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success')
    )
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you haven't added the  `Crispy Form tag` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings. Add this `'crispy_forms'` in there and should solve the problem, e.g.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
]
```

add these crisp tag in your templates.html should work just fine.

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
  {% csrf_token %}
{% crispy form %}
```

You can see more from [here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I had added the crispy_forms in the installed app so I guess that is not the problem

Comment: And for that you did `pip install django-crispy-forms`?

Comment: Yep before I even used crispy forms

Comment: @x_CrazyTeddy_x Omg, just noticed the amateur error, it's `crispy_forms_tags` not `crispy_form_tags`. Load the latter and it should solve your problem. Please also accept/upvote the answer if it helps in your problem

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem too, the server was running fine, then when I modified the app_tags, I get this same exact issue.

Django-crispy-forms was installed using pip install django-crispy-forms.
crispy_forms was added to the settings.py INSTALLED_APPS, but the problem persists.

So, apply all savings, restart your server, if the problem persists, restart your DB, and the IDE. That resolved it for me.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout